# List not printing all the Elements

Tags: c++, linked-list

So basically I created a linked list with the append and prepend functions and when I print the list it is only printing out 12 which I prepended to front of the list and not the other elements, how do I fix this issue? so that all the elements will be printed. I think that my append and prepend functions are correct but I do not know what could be wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    List* list = new List();
    list->Append(1);
    list->Append(2423);
    list->Prepend(12);
    list->print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

#include<iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

List::List() {
    this->HEAD = NULL;
    this->TAIL=NULL;
}
void List::Append(int Data_val) {
    NODE* Current = new NODE;
    Current->data = Data_val;

    if (HEAD == NULL) {

        HEAD = Current;
        TAIL = Current;
        Current->next = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        TAIL->next= Current;
        TAIL = Current;
        Current->next = nullptr;
    }
}
void List::Prepend(int data_val) {
    NODE* Current = new NODE;
    Current->data = data_val;
    if (HEAD = NULL) {
        Current->next = nullptr;
        HEAD = Current;
        TAIL = Current;

    }
    else {
        Current->next = HEAD;
        HEAD = Current;
        Current->next = nullptr;

    }
}
void List::print() {
    NODE* Current = HEAD;
    while (Current != NULL) {
        cout << Current->data << endl;
        Current=Current->next;
    }
}


#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

struct NODE {
    int data;
    NODE* next;
};
class List
{
    public:
        List();
        void Append(int data_val);
        void Prepend(int data_val);
        //create prepend
        //create insertafter
        //create delte
        void print();
    private:
        //
        NODE * HEAD;
        NODE* TAIL;
};
#endif
```

Comment: If this is `c++11`, then use `nullptr`, not `NULL`. But then you could just use `std::list`, instead of rolling your own... though I won't deny the exercise. :P Either way, `ALL CAPS` for anything except `#define`s and macro names is very bad style IMO.

Comment: @underscore_d: Nothing about this question is particular to C++11... I changed its tags.

Answer (score 0):

You havae a bug with your List::Prepand() method. The "Current->next = nullptr;"
line is not needed within "else" block.

```
void List::Prepend(int data_val) {
    NODE* Current = new NODE;
    Current->data = data_val;
    if (HEAD == NULL) {
        Current->next = nullptr;
        HEAD = TAIL = Current;
    }
    else {
        Current->next = HEAD;
        HEAD = Current;
        Current->next = nullptr;  // <---- remove this line
    }
}
```